# How to build a G Networkx using a python dict containing nodes and edges?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

Consider a list of tuples. This list will be converted to dictionary where main keys are nodes and edges.

Example:

```
ls = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('a', 2), ('b', 3)]
```

In order to achieve this result, I imported `networkx` library.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(ls)
```

However, when I converted *G graph* to `node_link_data`: `nx.readwrite.json_graph.node_link_data(G)` I figured out that some items (source and targets) were inverted, for example, the second item in the list of tuples was categorized as **source** instead **target**

```
# original tuple
('b', 2)

# node_link_data
links: [
  {'source': 2, 'target': 'b'}
  ...
]
```

So, I created my self the dict `{'nodes': [], 'links': []}`.

I want to use this dict to create the networkx graph. I am interested in measure nodes using the algorithms of this library.

I tried to use:

```
G = nx.Graph(myDict)
```

This returns an error: `TypeError: Input is not known type`

How can I build this graph using my dict that already contains nodes and edges? or perhaps, I can use other libraries to measure degrees, clustering, etc... using other libraries instead. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So the issue seems that some tuples aren't organized properly to do a consistent transformation from your list to a dictionary, what you could do is test the indexes of the tuples like so

```
ls = [('a', 1), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), ('a', 2), ('b', 3)]
links = []
for i in ls:
    try:
        if i[0].isalpha():
            links.append({'source': i[1], 'target': i[0]})
    except AttributeError:
        links.append({'source': i[0], 'target': i[1]})

print(links)
# [{'source': 1, 'target': 'a'}, {'source': 2, 'target': 'b'}, {'source': 3, 'target': 'c'}, {'source': 2, 'target': 'a'}, {'source': 3, 'target': 'b'}]
```

What happens is we test `i[0]` if its alphabetic with atleast one character, if it is we append that to targets and `i[1]` to source. On the other hand if it happens to be an `int` a error will be thrown and we can use `try/except` to catch that error and that tells us now that our int is in `i[0]` so we can create the dictionary with `i[0]` as source and `i[1]` as target.

Comment: Hi, @vash_the_stampede. The problem is not tranform the tuples in dictionaries. Actually, all data came from a postgresql database, so the order is ok.